# How to set file permissions so that new files inherit same permissions?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

I have a folder in which new subfolders and files will be created automatically, by a script.

I want to maintain the user and group permissions recursively for all new folders and files placed in the parent directory. I know this involves setting a sticky bit, but I can't seem to find a command that shows exactly what I need.

This is what I have done so far:

```
sudo mkdir -p /path/to/parent
sudo chmod -R 660 myself:somegroup /path/to/parent
```

Thereafter, I want the 660 permissions to be set recursively to any folders and files placed in `/path/to/parent`.

However, everything I have tried so far has failed. Can someone help please?

Actually the octal flag 660 is probably not even correct. The permissions I want are:

1. Directories placed under `/path/to/parent` are eXecutable by users with permissions
2. files are read/writeable by user myself and members of somegroup
3. Files and folders in `/path/to/parent` is NOT world readable

I am running on Ubuntu 10.0.4 LTS.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Grawity gives an excellent answer but I suspect the edited question may have changed things slightly.

I would suggest leaving the directory owned by the apache user/group. This will probably be either *apache* or *httpd* depending on your distribution.

e.g.

```
chown -R apache:apache /path/to/parent
```

You can then do something like https://serverfault.com/questions/164078/is-adding-users-to-the-group-www-data-safe-on-debian or even add yourself to the apache group to ensure you have group access to the directory. (Something like `usermod -aG apache username`)

I would not `chmod -R` the entire directory because you don't want html scripts or jpg's or random other things executable. You should change permissions as required. (though resetting it to 660 may not be the worst of ideas.)

Something you may like to try is:

```
chmod o+w file
```

The 'o' means 'other' & 'w' means 'write'. You can also have 'u' for 'user' & 'g' for 'group', as well as 'r' & 'x' which are hopefully self explanatory. You can remove permissions using '-' rather than '+'.

Comment: The simplest solution I think, is to add myself to the apache user group. Thanks for suggesting that. I don't know why I didn't think of that myself!

Comment: Is `o+w` a good choice here? Shouldn't the changes be limited to `u` and `g`? Otherwise, what's the point of trying to maintain security on the directory and sub-directories?

Answer (score 73):

The permission bits you are looking for are 0770 and 0660.

- `rw-` permissions → `110` binary → `6` octal

---

The *group ownership* can be inherited by new files and folders created in your folder /path/to/parent by setting the setgid bit using `chmod g+s` like this:

```
chmod g+s /path/to/parent
```

Now, all new files and folder created under /path/to/parent will have the same group assigned as is set on /path/to/parent.

---

POSIX file permissions are *not* inherited; they are given by the creating process and combined with its current umask value.

However, you can use [POSIX ACLs](http://www.suse.de/~agruen/acl/linux-acls/online/) to achieve this. Set the *default ACL* on a directory:

```
setfacl -d -m u::rwX,g::rwX,o::- /path/to/parent
```

This will apply `setfacl` to the /path/to/parent directory, `-m`odifying the *`-d`efault* ACLs – those that will be applied to newly created items. (Uppercase `X` means only directories will receive the `+x` bit.)

(If needed, you can add a `u:someuser:rwX` or `g:someuser:rwX` – preferably a group – to the ACLs.)

---

Note: On older systems using ext3/ext4, you used to need to mount the filesystem with the `acl` option, otherwise it would ignore all ACLs and disallow setting new ones.

```
mount -o remount,acl /
```

To set this permanently, use `tune2fs -o acl <device>` or edit `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Unfortunately, I am quite new to all of this, and what you wrote is indistinguishable from Greek to me (sorry to any Greek SO'ers!).  I did not understand most of what you wrote. I have a web process and I want to give Apache the ability to create folders and files in a parent folder where only Apache (the owner) and I (the group) have the ability to rw files and change into directories. Everyone else is banned. that is all I am trying to do. Apache needs to be able to create sub folders and store files in them.

Comment: This doesn't work with `unzip`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are over complicating the issue.  If the top level directory is not accessible to others, then others won't be able to create files within the tree.  Group write access is not required if only apache is doing the writing.

These steps should do what you want (replace directory in the commands with the directory you want to use):

- add `umask 027` to the apache defaults script `/etc/default/apache`. This will prevent other from accessing any files or directory apache creates.
- execute `chown www-data:www-data directory` on the directory you want apache to be able to write to.
- execute `chmod 750 directory` on the directory you want apache to be able to write to.

Allowing apache to write to a directory opens up the ability to inject all sort of malware to the content you are serving.  Monitor the contents of this directory tree appropriately.