# What permissions on /var/mail directory?

Tags: email, permissions, file-permissions, postfix

I've been suffering a permission problem in Postfix/Dovecot for a couple of days now. The setup is using virtual domains and users, so the path to user's `home` is `/var/mail/<domain>/<user>`; and the path to `MailDir` is `/var/mail/<domain>/<user>/MailDir`

The mail logs continue to show a *Permission Denied*:

```
Apr  3 05:44:16 debian-x2 postfix/virtual[5670]: D6DDD1780100: to=<jeff@deltoid.com>,
relay=virtual, delay=0.15, delays=0.1/0.01/0/0.04, dsn=4.2.0, status=deferred
(maildir delivery failed: create maildir file
/var/mail/deltoid.com/jeff/Maildir/tmp/1396518256.P5670.debian-x2: Permission denied)
```

Permissions are as follows:

```
# ls -l /var/mail/
total 96
drw-rws--- 4 vmail  vmail  4096 Apr  2 18:19 deltoid.com
-rw-rw---- 1 nobody mail  80586 Apr  2 07:45 nobody

# ls -l /var/mail/deltoid.com/
total 12
drw-rws--- 3 vmail vmail 4096 Apr  3 04:47 jeff
drw-rws--- 3 vmail vmail 4096 Apr  3 04:47 support
-rw-rws--- 1 vmail vmail  122 Apr  2 03:33 users

# ls -l /var/mail/deltoid.com/jeff/
total 4
drw-rws--- 2 vmail vmail 4096 Apr  3 04:47 Maildir

# ls -l /var/mail/deltoid.com/jeff/Maildir/
total 0
```

`vmail` is both a user and group, and its set to `id` 5000:

```
# id -u vmail
5000
```

`postfix` and `dovecot` are both in the `vmail` group:

```
# members vmail
vmail postfix dovecot
```

And Postfix's `main.conf`:

```
# Mailbox location
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
```

I have a little script that attempts to set the proper permission bits, but its apparently wrong:

```
# Ensure permissions are set on directories
chown -R vmail:vmail /var/mail/*.com
chmod -R 0660 /var/mail/*.com
chmod -R g+rwxs /var/mail/*.com
# chown -R dovecot:dovecot /var/mail/*.com/users
```

I got the `chmod -R g+rwxs` from SuperUser questions on setting directory permissions and having subdirectories and files inherit those permissions (for example, [How to set file permissions so that new files inherit same permissions?](https://superuser.com/questions/264383/set-file-permissions-so-that-new-files-inherit-same-permissions), [Setting default permissions for newly created files and sub-directories under a directory in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580584/setting-default-permissions-for-newly-created-files-and-sub-directories-under-a), and 
[How to make new file permission inherit from the parent directory?](https://superuser.com/questions/151911/how-to-make-new-file-permission-inherit-from-the-parent-directory)).

Two questions:

1. What is wrong with the current permissions?
2. What are the permissions supposed to be?

Comment: Your permission listing is missing the most important one, `/var/mail/deltoid.com/jeff/Maildir/tmp/`.

Comment: Thanks grawity. There is no `tmp/`. I added the output to the commands above. But the problem seems to be with permissions leading into the directory, and not the `tmp` directory. Otherwise, I'd get an `E_NOENT` error instead of `E_PERM` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions `drw-rws---` on directories are wrong because even the owner of the directory cannot go into them, due to the lack of the `x` bit (=`1` when using the numeric form).

You can test this by yourself by doing this as a normal user (not root):

```
$ mkdir -m 2670 /tmp/testdir
$ ls -ld /tmp/testdir
drw-rws--- 2 vmail vmail 4096 Apr  3 23:16 /tmp/testdir
$ cd /tmp/testdir
bash: cd: /tmp/testdir: Permission denied
```

I think that these lines in your current script:

```
chmod -R 0660 /var/mail/*.com
chmod -R g+rwxs /var/mail/*.com
```

should be instead:

```
chmod -R 2770 /var/mail/*.com
```